# IDE support for Arduino micro

Tags: ide, arduino-micro

I have an Arduino micro http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMicro I was looking to know which is the lowest version of the IDE that support it. Actually on the IDE 0023 is not present in `Tools > Board`.

Comment: Why are you still using 0023?

Comment: Find some very old .pde that works and is compatible with 002x

Comment: I don't think you're gonna get an answer here, as it's generally accepted to use the latest version, and we're gonna need to know why you don't want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Arduino Software Release Notes](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ReleaseNotes), support for the Arduino Micro was added in 1.0.2.